# Windows Phone 8 Unit Test stuck at "Running Tests"

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

I am trying to implement an unit test in my Windows Phone 8 application however the test runner wont recognize the tests. 
I am following this tutorial.

[Unit Testing In Windows Phone 8 The Basics](http://wp.qmatteoq.com/unit-testing-in-windows-phone-8-the-basics/)

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Testing;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace PPS.Tests 
{
[TestClass]
class SampleTest
{
    [Tag("SimpleTests")]
    [TestMethod]
    public void SimpleTest()
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 2;

        int c = a + b;

        Assert.IsTrue(c == 4);
    }
}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your test class needs to public, not interal (which it will be default) i.e.:

`public class SampleTest`